# Bibliography with hyperlinks in same style as AJ

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref

In Astronomical Journal articles I see bibliography styles, which include a pink DOI link and a blue NASA ADS link.

Example: See the figure.

[image]

**Image source:** http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/0004-6256/151/2/22/pdf

What needs to be done to reproduce this bibliography in my own latex document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please do not only add a link to your question, better create a screenshot and mark there what you are interested in. Add the screenshot to your question and add the code you have tried so far ...

Comment: Belated self-promotion: If you're willing to use biblatex, I made an ApJ style that inserts DOI, ADS, and arXiv links (github.com/EdwinChan/biblatex-apj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to modify the `aasjournal.bst` file to do something like this.

This solution gives almost the same as what you want. It only hyperlinks the volume, not the volume and pages. You can do this, but have to change a bit more.

Here's a patch file which you can use to make a new `bst` file. Save it as `aasjournal.bst.patch` then patch it as follows (linux commands):

```
$ cp aasjournal.bst aasjournal-hyperref.bst
$ patch aasjournal-hyperref.ast < aasjournal.bst.patch
```

**`aasjournal.st.patch`**

```
--- aasjournal.bst  2017-12-23 20:38:13.024114255 +1030
+++ aasjournal-hyperref.bst 2017-12-23 22:25:45.078409327 +1030
@@ -148,6 +148,7 @@
     year
     version
     url
+    adsurl
   }
   {}
   { label extra.label sort.label short.list }
@@ -1147,6 +1148,30 @@
     if$
 }

+%%%%%%% Custom href Functions
+
+FUNCTION {format.journal}
+{ journal empty$
+    { "" }
+    { doi empty$
+        { journal }
+        { "\href{http://dx.doi.org/" doi * "}{\color{magenta}" * journal * "}" * }
+      if$
+    }
+  if$
+}
+
+FUNCTION {format.vol}
+{ volume empty$
+    { "" }
+    { adsurl empty$
+        { volume }
+        { "\href{" adsurl * "}{\color{cyan}" * volume * "}" * }
+      if$
+    }
+  if$
+}
+
 %%%%%%%  End of functions from astrobib

 FUNCTION {article}
@@ -1157,9 +1182,8 @@
   format.date "year" output.check
   date.block
   crossref missing$
-    { journal
-      "journal" output.check
-      format.vol.num.pages output
+    { format.journal output
+      format.vol output
     }
     { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
       format.pages output
```

**MWE**

The bib entries are taken from the URLs.

```
\documentclass{aastex61}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{2011ApJ...738...13B,
   author = {{Batygin}, K. and {Brown}, M.~E. and {Fraser}, W.~C.},
    title = "{Retention of a Primordial Cold Classical Kuiper Belt in an Instability-Driven Model of Solar System Formation}",
  journal = {\apj},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
   eprint = {1106.0937},
 primaryClass = "astro-ph.EP",
 keywords = {Kuiper belt: general, planets and satellites: dynamical evolution and stability, methods: analytical, methods: numerical},
     year = 2011,
    month = sep,
   volume = 738,
      eid = {13},
    pages = {13},
      doi = {10.1088/0004-637X/738/1/13},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2011ApJ...738...13B},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
@ARTICLE{2013A&A...556A..28B,
   author = {{Batygin}, K. and {Morbidelli}, A.},
    title = "{Analytical treatment of planetary resonances}",
  journal = {\aap},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
   eprint = {1305.6513},
 primaryClass = "astro-ph.EP",
 keywords = {celestial mechanics, planets and satellites: dynamical evolution and stability, chaos},
     year = 2013,
    month = aug,
   volume = 556,
      eid = {A28},
    pages = {A28},
      doi = {10.1051/0004-6361/201220907},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013A%26A...556A..28B},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{aasjournal-hyperref}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Trying your method results in the error: " patching file aasjournal-hyperref.bst
Hunk #1 succeeded at 157 (offset 9 lines).
patch: **** malformed patch at line 23: journal * "}" * }
 " on the final command.

Comment: I have now patched by hand - and this solution worked well. Many thanks

Comment: Ah - I removed a line from the patch file forgetting that this breaks it. Sorry! I'll fix the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bibliography style for the A&A journal: https://github.com/yangcht/AA-bibstyle-with-hyperlink

The modified `aa.bst` file (called `aa_url.bst`) basically doing the same work, by using the `adsurl` entry and `doi` entry to create clickable hyperlinks.

Below you can find an example. 
[image]