# Astronomy Astrophysics bibliography with hyperlink

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, hyperlink

I am struggling to fix the hyperlink issue for A&A journal. The tricks mentioned in the link [Bibliography with hyperlinks in same style as AJ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407336/bibliography-with-hyperlinks-in-same-style-as-aj) adds two links (i) aanda and (ii) adsurl. But in A&A journals they use a single link. If we hover cursor on the list of refs then it is showing http://linker.aanda.org/10.. Can anyone please suggest how to do that?